# I am unable to add more than one line edittext android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

This is my XML property code. I am trying to add a multiline edittext in android, but unable to do so.

```
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Kindly enter the Delivery Address."
android:id="@+id/et_text"
android:layout_width="351dp"
android:``layout_height="153dp"
android:textDirection="firstStrong"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:lines="6"
android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
```

Comment: What do you mean "unable to do so"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `EditText` in android are multi-lined. 
Try this sample code.

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="6"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your edittext

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```